# iPhone SDK: Crop out unused part of UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, xcode4, uiimageview

I am making an application where an object moves according to tilt in my case, a soccer ball. I am trying to detect when the soccer ball is on a line which is displayed using a UIImageView. To detect whether the soccer ball is on the line or not I am using this piece of code.

```
 if ([line pointInside: [self.view convertPoint:buttonNewCenter toView: line] withEvent:nil]) {
    NSLog(@"inside");
}
```

This code works, however whenever the ball is inside the imageview but not the actualy line as shown in the picture: [image: ball being detected inside of image view when it shouldn't]

So, my question is if its possible to detect the ball inside the line and for it to not be detected when its not in the line and still in the image view. I've thought of maybe solving this by cropping the unused part of the image view but I'm not sure if it's possible. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't suggest doing that. I would suggest having "tiles," or like a polygon that will tell you when it's in or not (since the area seems to be curved). Something like: http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/